# VS code: Unable to start debugging - Program path is missing or invalid

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, googletest

I'm trying to use the debugger in vs code. I have problems to activate and run it.

This is my code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// Demonstrate some basic assertions.
TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {
  // Expect two strings not to be equal.
  EXPECT_STRNE("hello", "world");
  // Expect equality.
  EXPECT_EQ(7 * 6, 42);
}
```

VSCode reports that the program path is missing or invalid, even though I copied the address of the .exe file to the program path of launch.json, then GDB reports that the .exe file not in file format recognized. Any idea would be appreciate much. TY
This is the code in my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [
        ""
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Test",
      "environment": [],
      "program": "c:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Test/hello_test.exe",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit gdb and a 32-bit executable (or vice versa)

Comment: You can use this repo: https://github.com/ourarash/cpp-template
It uses Bazel for building your test programs. It also has the necessary settings to debug in VSC and adding breakpoints. More info on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfOzsBi_irY

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using all 64 bit version.